# Concatenate text in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have sql files in a folder structure like the following :

```
C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\SQL_FILES\data_structure\customer1\test.sql
C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\SQL_FILES\data_structure\customer2\test.sql
C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\SQL_FILES\data_structure\customer3\test.sql
C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\SQL_FILES\data_structure\customer4\test.sql
........
```

I want to make a script which reads the path (C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\SQL_FILES), 
the name of the file(test.sql) and a text
and then concatenate the text in the end of each test.sql file.

Could you help me please ?

Thanks in advance

```
:: Hide Command and Set Scope
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
mode 140,50


set /p AbsolutePath="Enter the path of root folder :"

echo.
set /p FileName="Enter the filename with it's extension (ie. test.sql):"

echo.
echo Enter your inserts
echo Press Enter twice when finished
echo (text may not contain  ^<, ^>, ^|, ^&, or un-closed quotes)

ver > NUL
set new_line=""
:still_typing
set /p new_line=">"
if errorlevel 1 echo. >> temp.txt & set /p new_line=">"
if errorlevel 1 echo Sending message. . . & goto done_typing
echo      %new_line% >> temp.txt
goto still_typing

:done_typing
echo done

:End
endlocal
pause >nul
```

=====================================

For example :
The file test.sql for example contains initially :

```
INSERT INTO TEST(COL1,COL2,COL3) VALUES(3,4,5);
```

And after the execution of batch supposing I add an empty line and two inserts in the text :

```
INSERT INTO TEST(COL1,COL2,COL3) VALUES(3,4,5);

INSERT INTO TEST(COL1,COL2,COL3) VALUES (1,2,3);

INSERT INTO TEST(COL1,COL2,COL3) VALUES (2,3,4);
```

Comment: Please provide an example of your starting data, and an example of what you would like the results to be.

Comment: The better verb would be `append` not `concatenate` but aside from appending lines to `temp.txt` (without initializing the file) there is no loop to iterate the folders/files and do the appending via copy or `type test.txt >> test.sql`

Comment: I modified the initial question.Thank you

Comment: 1. I see no references other than the setting of values for `AbsolutePath` or `FileName`. 2. This would probably be easier to do in a language other than cmd-batch; I'd suggest PowerShell, but VBScript or JScript are also reasonable possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Batch file below use a different method to do the same, but in a simpler way. This code may be modified in any point you wish; for example, if you want not that the filename must include a wild-card.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /p "AbsolutePath=Enter the path of root folder: "
echo/
set /p "FileName=Enter the filename with a wild-card (ie. test*.sql): "
echo/

echo Enter your inserts
echo Press Ctrl-Z and Enter when finished
copy CON temp.txt > NUL
echo/
echo Typing done
echo/

for /R "%AbsolutePath%" %%a in (%FileName%) do type temp.txt >> "%%a"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but in case I have files like testFile.txt add also the text to this.
How can I avoid this ? I tried test.sql* and it works ..